# $locationChangeSuccess fires 4 times when accesing/exiting the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

trying to debug $locationChangeSuccess while entering/exiting a page for multiple times. that said when entering it fires twice while on exiting it fires 4 times as I can see from my tests. the code is placed within the controller at the very begining. what am I doing wrong ?

on first enter it's not triggered.

on first exit is triggered once

on second entering is triggered once

next time on both it's triggered twice and it multiplies to 4 after

```
  var counter = 0;
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
      console.log(current);
      console.log(previous);
      console.log(counter);
      console.log('------------');
      counter++
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should not be inside a controller. It should be inside run method.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous){
  console.log(current);
  console.log(previous);
  console.log(counter);
  console.log('------------');
  counter++ 
});
}]);
```